# Событие после полной загрузки HTML5 видео

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Есть HTML страница на которой плавно по таймеру появляются элементы (jQuery):

```
$(window).ready(function(){    
    $("#site--header").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

В верхней части HTML страницы есть видео. Как сделать так, чтобы появление элементов начиналось после 100% загрузки видео HTML5, которое есть на странице?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно документации [События в медиа (audio, video) объектах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events), не существует пока событий, которые отправляются после 100% загрузки видео.

Но есть события oncanplaythrough и oncanplay, которые, возможно, вам подойдут:

```
my_video.oncanplaythrough = function(e)
{
    //Событие отправляется, когда состояние готовности изменяется к CAN_PLAY_THROUGH. Указывает, что медиа может быть полностью воспроизведено без перерыва, предполагая, что скорость загрузки остается, по крайней мере на нынешнем уровне. Примечание: Ручная установка CURRENTTIME вызовет событие canplaythrough в Firefox. В других браузерах это может не произойти.
}

my_video.oncanplay = function(e)
{
    //Событие отправляется, когда доступно достаточно данных для того, чтобы медиа могло воспроизвестись, по крайней мере, в течение нескольких кадров. Соответствует состоянию (readyState) HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA.
}
```

Comment: Действительно, сработало. Однако желаемая цель не достигнута - всё равно при появлении видео первые 1-2 секунды наблюдаются тормоза. Но решение работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

никак это не реализуется простым плеером HTML5...

Comment: А `canplaythrough`?